# Password and passhash handling practices java web app

Tags: java, security, passwords, password-hash

Good day,
I create a web application in Java, using plain JDBC
I have the following architecture:
Domain Model - Service Layer - DAO Layer
Service Layer is a middle man in CRUD operations

My User class has field "password" (User.password)
My User table in DB has column "pass_hash" 
I use BCrypt from spring.security and therefore do not store salt as a distinct column

Questions:

1. Which fields do I need to have in Domain model layer to handle passwords? password field? passHash field? both fields? other thoughts?
2. After reading stack overflow, I caught an idea not to include pass_hash, when I create a user instance, unless really needed for security purposes. The question is what layer should I omit the pass_hash: DAO? Service layer? AFAIU DAO layer should be responsible only for DB communication, so I do not make additional filters there and read user from db **completely** with pass_hash. Then I set password to null in a Service Layer as you see in read method below.
3. What layer should contain hashing: DAO/Service? I use service (create method below)

**UserService** methods example

```
@Override
public Long create(User user) {
    String hashedPassword = BCrypt.hashpw(user.getPassword(),
        BCrypt.gensalt(BCRYPT_SALT_LOG_ROUNDS));
    user.setPassword(hashedPassword);
    return userDao.create(user);
}

@Override
public User read(Long id) {
    User user = userDao.read(id);
    if (user != null) {
        user.setPassword(null);
    }
    return user;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: May be you could be so kind to tell what's wrong with my question instead of putting "-" without any comment

Answer (score 0):

Just save the BCrypt password hash, not the password itself.

Comment: That is what I do, I have only "pass_hash" column in DB. I keep only hashed password there.

Comment: But, what doest it mean? Do I need to have two fields inside my User class or only one field? What layer do I have to use for hashing password? Should I avoid selecting password hash, when I read User record from DB? How should I do this if I should?

Comment: 1. On registration run the password through BCrypt and save the hash along with the user id in the DB. 2. On login run the password through BCrypt, retrieve the hash from the user id record from the DB and compare.